"dass er bald lange Urlaub macht"
This is yet another sentence that Duolingo throws my way that I find odd and puzzling.

Warum hat Oscar gesagt, dass er bald lange Urlaub macht?

Since Urlaub is a masculine singular noun, here used without an article, shouldn't the strong declension apply, thus calling for "langen" in the accusative, much like "Haben Sie vielen Dank"?

On a side note: "lange Urlaub machen" sometimes serves as an euphemism for "(having to) go to jail".

Yes, indeed - but here "Urlaub machen" is treated as a fixed noun + verb construct, and thus "lange" is an adverb which describes the activity, and is not an adjective to the noun.
One can see the distinction in these two similar sentences:

Ich fahre schnell Fahrrad (I cycle quickly)


Ich fahre ein schnelles Fahrrad" (I cycle a fast bike)


This isn't an adjective, but an adverb: "that he will soon go on vacation for a long time", not "go on a long vacation" (which would be "einen langen Urlaub").
